# How to find out the total memory used by an aerospike set

Tags: caching, aerospike

I would like to know how we can list down the memory usage per set of an aerospike cache?

Answer (score 2):

You should have the answer on the [How to determine storage per set](https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/how-to-determine-storage-per-set/6291) knowledge base article. The article is a bit long because it depends on the configuration (in memory or not), if the sought after number is for how much is used on storage or in memory, and depends on the version number.

For latest versions, it is straight forward, there is a metric for the storage size for a set: [device_data_bytes](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/metrics/index.html?show-removed=1#device_data_bytes). And for the memory portion, the [sets](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/info/index.html#sets) info command will return the metric for the size of a set in memory.